# How to use One hot encoded data (3dim) as input for a feed forward neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am currently working with some DNA sequences and building a feed forward network that classifies them.
Therefore I one hot encode my data so that a example sequences changes like this:

```
seq = "ACGT" ---> one_hot_encoded = [[[0. 0. 0.]
                                      [1. 0. 0.]
                                      [0. 1. 0.]
                                      [0. 0. 1.]]]
```

This one hot encoded sequence has a shape of (1,4,3) .For a large dataset the shape  would obviously be (n , len(sequence), 3 )

My question now is: how do I feed this data in a standard feed forward neural network?
I have only worked with data that had this shape : `(n, num_features)`

Or to make it more general how do I work with 3 dimensional input data?

I am coding with tensorflow, and have so far implemented
a sequential model which looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(24, input_shape=(?), activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(48, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(6, activation="softmax"))
```

so I want to have as many input features as my sequence is long, so based
on my above example that would be 4.

I don't know how I get my input  with shape (1,4,3) into this model in such way that in the end
I get 6 probabilities.

Comment: Would you please elaborate your question? Which framework you are coding with? If for example Tensorflow, how did you define your model? Sequential or Functional API?

Comment: I don't know if `one hot encoded` fit to this problem. It is good when you may have one value in column `A` or `C` or `G` or `T` - and then it split it into 4 columns `A,C,G,T` and put values `1,0` in these coulms. When you would have only `A` then it puts in columns `A,C,G,T` values `1,0,0,0`, etc. But maybe better ask on similar portal for [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @KavehShahhoseini elaborated a bit, I hope that helps